# Regex pattern to find plus and equal sign

Tags: javascript, python, regex

Hey I'm looking for a `regex` pattern to search through a string example:

`++t+==+z++==` and return **true** if a letter is surrounded by a `+` on both sides. Otherwise its **false**

- `++t++z==` will return **false**.
- `++z+p++`  will return **true**.
- `t++z+`    will return **false**.

A code sample of the function in js

```
function check_str_pos(str){
///(\+|=|[a-zA-Z])|(\+[a-zA-Z]\+)|(\+|=|[a-zA-Z])$/

   if(/^(\+[a-zA-Z]\+)$/.test(str))
   {

  return true;
}

 else{

   return false;
  }
   }
```

Comment: Pretty simple. `\+[a-zA-Z]\+` if you are using your definition of _"... **true** if a letter is surrounded by a + on both sides"_. But your definition doesn't match your examples, such as `++t++z==` because `t` is a letter, and on both sides of it are plus signs. Yet you claim that is **false** somehow.

Comment: You don't need regex to solve this.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs tried that is not working.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat what do I need then.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the RegExp you are looking for is:

```
var reEx = new RegExp(/^\++\w*\W*\w*\++$/);

console.log(reEx.test('++t++z==')); //false
console.log(reEx.test('++z+p++'));  //true
console.log(reEx.test('t++z+'));    //false
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is an option to first remove the equals signs `=` using replace and then check what is left using this pattern [`^\++(?:[a-z]\++)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/YbFZ7W/1).

This will match a `+` from the beginning of the string `^` and repeat `[a-z]` followed by one or more times a `+` until the end of the string `$`.

```js
const strings = [
  "++t+==+z++==",
  "++z+p++",
  "++t++z==",
  "t++z+",
  "#$==f+fdfd+fdfd+45545"
];
let pattern = /^\++(?:[a-z]\++)+$/;

strings.forEach((s) => {
  let x = s.replace(/=/g, '');
  console.log(s + " ==> " + pattern.test(x));
});
```